# How to use FormArray in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I creating form

```
createProduct = new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl([''], Validators.required),
        category: new FormControl(),
        nomenclature: new FormControl(),
        descriptions: new FormControl(),
        models: new FormArray([
            new FormControl
        ])
    });

 get models() {
        return this.createProduct.controls['models'] as FormArray;
    }
```

and get an array of fields from the server.

```
 character(id = 1) {
        this.server.index('characteristic/?' + 'id=' + id).subscribe(response => {
            this.characters = response
        })
    }
```

Next, I want to build a form for the user,

```
 <div class="in-group mb-1" formArrayName="models">
                        <div *ngFor="let forms of models.controls">
                            <div *ngFor="let char of characters">
                                <label for="{{char.id}}">{{char.name}}</label>
                                <select class="form-control w-25" id="{{char.id}}" [formControlName]    =char.id>
                                    <option *ngFor="let val of char.value" value="{{val.id}}">{{val.value}}</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I can’t figure out how to properly name the fields for accepting answers, there can be as many fields as you like and grouped by condition

I don't know what to write here anymore...

Comment: If you create a suitable title for your question
More people can help you solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you gave of your code was a little unclear to me. But I understood your general meaning of the problem you encountered.

I made a simple example that can solve your problem

//// section html

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="models">
    <div *ngFor="let item of form.get('models')['controls']; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <label for="{{item.value.id}}">{{item.value.name}}</label>
      <select class="form-control w-25" id="{{item.value.id}}" formControlName="dataSelect">
          <option *ngFor="let val of item.value.selectModel" value="{{val.id}}">{{val.value}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button (click)="testForm()">test</button>
```

////// section typescript

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  form: FormGroup;
  dataExampleModelsFormArray;

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.form = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl([''], Validators.required),
      category: new FormControl(),
      nomenclature: new FormControl(),
      descriptions: new FormControl(),
      models: new FormArray([])
    });

    this.getData();

    this.dataExampleModelsFormArray.map(x => {
      (this.form.get('models') as FormArray).push(
        this.fb.group({
          id: x.id,
          name: x.name,
          selectModel: this.fb.array([...x.selectModel]),
          dataSelect: x.dataSelect
        })
      )
    })
  }

  getData() {
    this.dataExampleModelsFormArray = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'label_1',
        selectModel: [
          { id: 1, value: 'select1_1' },
          { id: 2, value: 'select1_2' },
          { id: 3, value: 'select1_3' },
        ],
        dataSelect: ''
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'label_2',
        selectModel: [
          { id: 1, value: 'select2_1' },
          { id: 2, value: 'select2_2' },
          { id: 3, value: 'select2_3' },
        ],
        dataSelect: ''
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'label_3',
        selectModel: [
          { id: 1, value: 'select3_1' },
          { id: 2, value: 'select3_2' },
          { id: 3, value: 'select3_3' },
        ],
        dataSelect: ''
      }
    ]
  }

testForm() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
```

Here, when the select boxes are filled. Their value is stored in the dataSelect key.

This is how you can have a completely dynamic form that has inputs like select inside that form.

Comment: Thank you for your care and willingness to help.
Indeed, the problem is not correctly described, I cannot understand how I can accept data from forms if their "name" has an undefined wording.
In normal Html I would do name="name[data.server.name][]". I would use the name of the question and write answers to it, but in angular it seems to be different

Comment: [formGroupName]="i"> 
Apparently this is what I need to distribute responses by type

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delay
You put the output that comes from the server side into the getData() function
and put its output into a variable according to the example I gave you
(Note I made an example to give you a good idea to solve your problem)


Then put a loop inside that variable and according to the example put all the things you want to display in the html into it